# How to check when silverlight Listbox is updated

Tags: silverlight, listbox

How do I check when a listbox is updated, or when its item count changes? I can only capture the SelectionChanged event now.

I'm trying to select any new item when initially added to the listbox binded DocItemCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DocItemCollection is an observable collection (or at least implements INotifyCollectionChanged) you can watch it by subscribing to : DocItemCollection.CollectionChanged and see if it is an insert or a delete.